# Python packages required to run RStudio Quarto files in VS Code

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, r-markdown, quarto

I have been trying to run RStudio Quarto script in a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation but got into some trouble. Some Python packages that are required to run the simple `hello.qmd` were not there. I was getting these errors:

`MoudleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbclient'`

and a second error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib_inline'`

Answer (score 1):

The first error was due to I had install the `nbclient` package. My default Python installation is `python2.7`. Quarto will not run well with Python 2.7; we should try with 3.7+. If your Linux doesn't come with it by default, this can easily be addressed by installing another Python version and configuring multiple Python versions with the help of the command:

`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

If no Python version shows up, then it means you have first to configure all your installed Python versions. This is very well explained at https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-and-switch-python-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Once you have configured all your Python versions, every time that you run
`sudo update-alternatives --config python`, you will be prompted to enter the Python version you want as default. If you have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04, most likely that you have two: Python 2.7 and Python 3.8. Select 3.8 and you will fine. Quarto won't work with `Python 2.7`.

After you have `python3` running and switched into, install `nbclient` with:
`pip install nbclient`.

The first error will now pass, but most likely you will get now
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib_inline'`. This is because you also need to install the package `matplotlib-inline`. This is not documented in the installation instructions of Quarto. But easy to fix. Run:

`pip install matplotlib-inline`

Now, go back to your VS Code, open the command palette and run `Quarto: Render`, or just type from the terminal:

`quarto preview hello.qmd --no-browser --no-watch-inputs`

You are done!

[image]

Comment: For future references check out https://quarto.org/docs/computations/python.html#installation